# Is having a unit test that is mostly mock verification a smell?

Tags: python, unit-testing, language-agnostic, tdd

I have a class that connects three other services, specifically designed to make implementing the other services more modular, but the bulk of my unit test logic is in mock verification. Is there a way to redesign to avoid this?

Python example:

```
class Input(object): pass

class Output(object): pass

class Finder(object): pass

class Correlator(object): pass
  def __init__(self, input, output, finder):
    pass
  def run():
    finder.find(input.GetRows())
    output.print(finder)
```

I then have to mock input, output and finder. Even if I do make another abstraction and return something from Correlator.run(), it will still have to be tested as a mock.

Comment: What's exactly your problem? I have classes that need up to eight dependencies... if your design is correct and you think your abstractions are consistent, I wouldn't change your code.

Comment: I think the thing that was bothering me was that the class's sole purpose is integration, so the best way to test that would be an integration test. I've always strived for independent unit tests first then integration tests as the architecture matures. Guess I'll just have to let this one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ask yourself: what exactly do you need to check in this particular test case? If this check does not rely on other classes not being dummy, then you are OK.

However, a lot of mocks is usually a smell in sense that you are probably trying to test integration without actually doing integration. So if you assume that if the class passes test with mocks, it will be fine working with real classes, than yes, you have to write some more tests.

Personally, I don't write many Unit tests at all. I'm web developer and I prefer functional tests, that test the whole application via HTTP requests, as users would. Your case may be different

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to only use unit test - Maybe integration tests would be more useful for this case. Initialize all the objects properly, use the main class a bit, and assert on the (possibly complex) results. That way you'll test interfaces, output predictability, and other things which are important further up the stack. I've used this before, and found that something which is difficult to integration test probably has too many attributes / parameters or too complicated/wrongly formatted output.

Answer (score 0):

On a quick glance, this do look like the level of mocking becomes to large. If you're on a dynamic language (I'm assuming yes here since your example is in Python), I'd try to construct either subclasses of the production classes with the most problematic methods overridden and presenting mocked data, so you'd get a mix of production and mocked code. If your code path doesn't allow for instantiating the objects, I'd try [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) in replacement methods returning mock data.

Weather or not this is code smell also depends on the quality of mocked data. Dropping into a debugger and copy-pasting known correct data or sniffing it from the network is in my experience the preferred way of ensuring that.

Integration vs unit testing is also an economical question: how painful is it to replace unit tests with integration/functional tests? The larger the scale of your system, the more there is to gain with light-weight mocking, and hence, unit tests.